# How to instantiate shared pointer with JNI to call java implementation

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm new in JNI and C++. I have to call lib function with shared pointer. My code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_test_NativeClient_subscribe(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObj, jobject handler) {
jclass handlerClass = env->GetObjectClass(handler);
jmethodID starts = env->GetMethodID(handlerClass, "starts", "(I)V");
jmethodID joins = env->GetMethodID(handlerClass, "joins", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");

// int subscribe(std::shared_ptr< SomeHandler > handler) // I need implement this
 
 std::shared_ptr<?> sharedPointer = new std::shared_ptr<?>;
 
return some::lib::subscribe(sharedPointer);
}
```

SomeHandler it is an interface from lib - some::lib::SomeHamdler, but also I pass java implementation in the method (jobject handler). How I can properly define sharedPointer to call java implementation after subscribe method performed? Thanks in advance.

UPD: Java code:

```
public native int subscribe(SomeHandler handler); // native method in NativeClient
```

SomeHandler interface:

```
public interface SomeHandler {

void starts(int uptime);

void joins(String mac, String name);
```

SomeHandlerImpl class:

```
public class SomeHandlerImpl implements SomeHandler {

@Override
public void starts(int uptime) {
    System.out.println("uptime is " + uptime);
}

@Override
public void joins(String mac, String name) {
    System.out.println("mac: " + mac + ", nName: " + name);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a class which derives from SomeHandler, and when your class's handler is called, it calls the Java handler.

Comment: Yes, I already have java interface SomeHandler and its implementation SomeHandlerImpl. I'll add java code.

Comment: Okay, but you're talking about C++ code here so obviously you need a class that `some::lib::subscribe` can use, which is a C++ class.

Comment: As I understand from my task, it is required to call java implementation after subscription. I.e. subscribe will invoke starts and joins methods.

Comment: What is some::lib::subscribe?

Comment: It is a function to subscribe to some events using the notification handler (SOmeHandler). some::lib is a placeholder. It is a quite real implementation but I can't share it here. some::lib::subscribe calls int subscribe(std::shared_ptr< SomeHandler > handler) function

Comment: So i need something like std::shared_ptr<some::lib::SomeHandler> sharedPointer = GetSharedPointer(handlerClass); But i don't know how to write GetSharedPointer... in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is store a global reference to the `jobject` and write some wrapper code:

```
class JavaWrapperHandler : public some::lib::callback {
    jobject java_handler;

public:
    JavaWrapperHandler(jobject handler) {
        JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
        vm->GetEnv(&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        java_handler = env->NewGlobalRef(handler);
    }

    ~JavaWrapperHandler() {
        JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
        vm->GetEnv(&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        env->DeleteGlobalRef(java_handler);
    }

    virtual joins(std::string mac, std::string name) {
        JNIEnv *env = nullptr;
        vm->GetEnv(&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
        jclass handlerClass = env->GetObjectClass(java_handler);
        jmethodID joins = env->GetMethodID(handlerClass, "joins", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        env->CallVoidMethod(java_handler, joins, ...);
    };
};
```

And you can instantiate this as follows in your JNI method:

```
std::make_shared<JavaWrapperHandler>(handler);
```

Note that you still need to *store* the `shared_ptr` again somewhere, otherwise it will immediately be freed. You could for example store it in a `std::map<long, shared_ptr<JavaWrapperHandler>>` and return the `long` as a `jlong`.

Points of note:

- This code keeps a global reference to prevent the Java handler object from being garbage collected.
- The global reference is freed when the handler is destroyed. Make sure to unregister the callback at some point if you want to free the Java object.
- We use the GetEnv method from the JNI Invocation API. It will only produce a useful value if the current (C++) thread has already been attached to the JVM. If it fails, you need to call `vm->AttachCurrentThread` or `vm->AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon`.

Comment: The quite simple and obvious solution. Thanks a lot! Why you instantiate *env in constructor and method? And where you get VM variable? Can I use env from Java_com_test_NativeClient_subscribe in JavaWrapperHandler constructor and methods?

Comment: No, you cannot share `JNIEnv* env` across threads, that is why I retrieve it every time for the current thread. It was unclear from your explanation, so I assumed your "somelib" uses a separate thread to invoke callbacks, which is different from the subscribing thread. Retrieving the `env` associated with the current thread solves that. As I said, you may need to attach it the thread the first time a callback fires. If you did not create the VM yourself you can use [`env->GetJavaVM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp23168)

Comment: I get error - " 'GetEnv' was not declared in this scope". And also -" note: suggested alternative: ‘setenv’"
How I can fix it?

Comment: It should be part of the jni header. Did you not include it?

Comment: Did you mean #include <jni.h> ? I tried and got the same.

Comment: Sorry, I was too quick. `GetEnv` is a method of the VM object. So you need to do `vm->GetEnv(...)`. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it works. I wrote working code here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63032634/7804595